# How to send dtmf tones using BlackBerry API?

Tags: blackberry, dtmf

I have tried to use

```
    PhoneArguments phoneArgs = new PhoneArguments(PhoneArguments.ARG_CALL, num);
    Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_PHONE, phoneArgs);
    PhoneCall call = Phone.getActiveCall();
    call.sendDTMFTones(tones);
```

but it doesnt work.

Can anyone point me to a working code snippet for sending DTMF?

regards

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Did you try sending them one at a time? Are you checking the return value of `sendDTMFTones()` ?

```
PhoneCall pc = new PhoneCall();
boolean added = pc.sendDTMFTone(7);
```